# what's means of CFLAGS_vmx which is in kvm Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, kvm

I'm reading about the kvm modules. I can't understand the CFLAGS_vmx.o in the Makefile of kvm. I guess that it is to add "-I" option to compile the vmx.c. Is it the implicit deduction rules of Makefile?(I don't know how to search it.)

```
CFLAGS_x86.o := -I.
CFLAGS_svm.o := -I.
CFLAGS_vmx.o := -I.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Those are just three make variables. Presumably somewhere else in the make process one (or the other) of those variables is used in appropriate rules (possibly dynamically).

Comment: I have seach other Makefile, there is no use in others. It is only in the kvm modules' Makefile. It is so weird.

Comment: Given the naming those are almost certainly dynamically used. So you would be looking for `$(CFLAGS_$(SOME_VAR))` or `$(CFLAGS_$(SOME_VAR).o)` uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess that it is to add "-I" option to compile the vmx.c.

Yes, variable `CFLAGS_<name>.o` defines compilation flags, which are used for compile file `<name>.c` (usually) into `<name>.o`.

These variables and others, which are used in kernel's makefiles, are described in [Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt).